# While optional, unwrap if contains something

Tags: swift, do-while

The context : I have a generic stack of objects. The stack responds to pop() (returns an optional) and I have a function that needs to process the stack

- If the stack is empty, throw an error
- Otherwise, repeat repeat operation until next optional is not unwrappable

So far

```
guard var nextVar = myStack.pop() else {
   throw MyError.EmptyStack
}

repeat {
    // Process nextVar
} while nextVar = myStack.pop()
```

Problem : the first nextVar is NOT an Optional, therefore my while call fails. How can I rewrite so that the while checks whether the optional contains something AND if that succeeds, assign the content to the variable ? ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify your stack type to include an `isEmpty` property. Then you won't need to duplicate the `pop` call, and this will be a simple `while-let` loop.

```
guard !myStack.isEmpty else {
   throw MyError.EmptyStack
}

while let nextVar = myStack.pop() {
    // Process nextVar
}
```

---

You can also convert this into a `SequenceType`, but then iterating won't consume the stack. Then this would just be:

```
guard !myStack.isEmpty else {
   throw MyError.EmptyStack
}

for nextVar in myStack {
    // Process nextVar
}
```

Since `pop` is exactly the needed implementation of `GeneratorType.next()`, it should be easy to turn this into a `GeneratorType` and a `SequenceType` (by returning `self` in `generate()`).

But since `Stack` is a value type, iterating over it with `for-in` will make a copy and then consume that copy, rather than consuming the original stack. That could be good or bad.

Here's a sketch of what I mean:

```
struct Stack<Element> {
    private var stack: [Element] = []
    mutating func push(element: Element) {
        stack.append(element)
    }

    mutating func pop() -> Element? {
        guard let result = stack.last else { return nil }
        stack.removeLast()
        return result
    }

    var isEmpty: Bool { return stack.isEmpty }
}

extension Stack: GeneratorType {
    mutating func next() -> Element? {
        return pop()
    }
}

extension Stack: SequenceType {
    func generate() -> Stack {
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor remark: If you adopt both SequenceType *and* GeneratorType then you don't have to implement generate(), there is a default implementation.